# How to generate documentation for fixtures in Fitnesse Tests

Tags: c#, c++, fitnesse

I'm working in project which is using `Fitnesse` for a few years. One of important topic is to maintenance and add new tests. To avoid duplication is good to have some documentation for existing `fixtures`. 
Do you know tools which can maybe generate documentation for `fixtures` from `C#` or `C++` code?

Answer (score 0):

I mostly work in Java and have encountered teams that generated documentation for their fixtures based on JavaDoc (equivalent of xmldoc). They created their own source post processor that generated wiki pages describing each fixture and each method based on these comments. 
I'm sure something similar can be created (if it doesn't exist already) for the .Net environment.

My personal experience is that writing documentation for fixtures goes beyond what I can achieve in comments in my code. For each of the main fixtures in my open source library I have created an overview page listing all methods (the domain specific language the define) and below that I added multiple example test pages showing the fixtures in action. Furthermore I create FitNesse acceptance tests for my fixtures which also provide documentation (of sorts). All this is manual work, which I believe is important to allow people to benefit from the fixtures.

So I believe you probably get better documentation by spending the time writing the documentation by hand than spending it to set up the generator and ensure proper input is present in your fixtures code.... Just my 2cts.